# Can I remove directory after $git clone and $make install

Tags: cmake, makefile, installation

I wrote myself a litte script to install opencv under ubuntu14.04. Can I remove the directory 3party after the `make install` sorted the lib into system directories or are there dependencies? (Remove not only the MYBUILD but the complete 3party)

```
echo "\nInstall OpenCV?...<any key>\n"
read inp1; # $inp1
mkdir 3party;

cd 3party;
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
    cd opencv;
    mkdir MYBUILD;
    cd MYBUILD;
    #sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/opencv;
    cmake -L -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. ;
    echo"check if path is ok?...<any key> or abort";
    read inp1; # $inp1
    make;
    #sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/opencv;
    make install;

cd ../../..;
chmod -R 777 3party;
echo "\nDone.\nPlease exit...<any key>";
```

EDIT: I did tag it cmake because the configuration step is performed with [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html) build tool. Also the [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) on the OpenCV website stated it. Please correct me if wrong.

> Building OpenCV from Source Using CMake, Using the Command Line

Comment: After make install you can delete `3party`. But how is this question related to CMake or make? Poor tagging, poor questions. Downvoting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, after installation of any package its source and binary directories can be safetly removed. OpenCV follows this convention too.

Comment: It should be pointed out that if you **ever** want to *uninstall* the version you just installed from source having the original source directory is the easiest way to do that (assuming the project has a reasonable 'uninstall' target).

Comment: @EtanReisner: Having `make uninstall` is a *good* practice.. but is not the *universal* one. E.g., CMake has no builtin `uninstall` target. Some other projects have `uninstall` script, which is installed. And finally, uninstalling things is not the most common usage.. I am unsure that it is worth to note `make uninstall` here.

Comment: An `uninstall` target *should* be default. I consider it, yet another, poor CMake decision if it isn't standard (especially since they handle generating the Makefiles and could fairly trivially (I think) create a matching installer (or at least an attempt at one). Uninstall scripts are not uncommon but are still unfortunate and still make keeping the original source around a good idea. And uninstalling *should* be entirely common since it should be part of upgrades too (unless some other management tool is in use as well).

Comment: Yes, CMake allows to simply [create](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Can_I_do_.22make_uninstall.22_with_CMake.3F) `uninstall` target. Note, that such target requires not only source files, but also a **build tree** (at least, one file from it). But one can also create `uninstall` script and install it within `make install` process, so neither source nor build tree are not needed for this script to work. Again, I agree that `make uninstall` is *good* thing, but it is **not strongly required as** having installed files not dependent from existence of source and build files.